# How do i fix an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0" in Windows desktop application

Tags: .net, windows, rdlc

The application is a fairly simple WPF application that lets the user produce simple reports. The reports are produced with Microsoft RDLC Report Designer and generated using Microsoft Reporting Services.

The app was running fine in production for over a year, but users started experiencing this error just today. 
The server admins tell me that no changes have been done on this server, i.e no updates and no new software installations.

My application does reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Types but Copy Local property is set to True for it:

[image]

and I verified that Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll (of version 12.0.0.0) is copied into the application's folder.

The definition file for the report `Reports/ShipmentSummaryReport.rdlc` is also present in the application folder and has not been changed since the production deployment.

The full Exception stack is following:

```
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. 
---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'Reports/ShipmentSummaryReport.rdlc' is invalid. 
---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. 
---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(Object obj, Boolean verify, Boolean assertOnInvalidType)
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking around the support topics and forums, I figured that the following folder and the .dll was missing on the machine that hosts the application:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
```

I created the folder and downloaded v 12.0.0.0 of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/ into this folder.

Restarted the app and reports worked.